# Under any general matrix transformations, the image of a square will always be some type of quadrilateral.

Tags: matrices, geometry

Under any general matrix transformations, the image of a square will always be some type of quadrilateral.

I feel this is true because transformations preserve the shape but im trying to look for a counterexample and cant seem to find one

Answer (score 1):

Linear transformations either preserve straight lines or collapse them to a point. So if you count points as degenerate line segments, then yes any linear transformation maps a quadrilateral to another quadrilateral.